# Database during release and developing

Tags: mysql, database, eclipse

I am new to Database programming and there is some general questions that I would like to ask. I created the schema in my localhost using mySQL and linked to eclipse. There are some problems that I do not know how to approach.

One of my friends would like to help to develop at his personal machine, but he could not link to my database server. So one way is to copy the schema to his mySQL and change the connection string, are there any better ways?

If I would to release the project and run it on different machines, will it affect the databases operation since the schema resides in my local server.

Is there ways to just like attach the database inside the project since it is a local database and I am not accessing it from any other programs.

Sorry if my questions sound very stupid. I am really new.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of running local test MySQL instance for every developer sounds fine.

However, if your application never needs any data shared (essentially database is always local as you stated), then you should ask yourself if MySQL really an appropriate solution for your application. I think [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) is a better choice in that situation - it is likely to work faster than MySQL for local access, and it has essentially zero setup - no database daemon to run or anything like that which greatly simplifies application install.

Granted, SQLite has its limits, but I often use SQLite for my projects, and only if they grow large, I might migrate them to MySQL or PostgreSQL if task requires it.

Typical signs that SQLite may not cut it:

- Many clients (10+) need to access database for writing
- Total database size is very large - more than 10GB total

Comment: So for SQLite, is there any GUI for me work with? Which allows me to create tables, assign keys and stored procedures much easier.

Comment: There are many excellent SQLite browsers/editors out there. I like [SQLite Expert Personal](http://sqliteexpert.com) on Windows and [sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com) on Linux. There is also SQLite editor plugin for Firefox. For more info, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14700226/1734130).