# How can I represent a 2-dimensional array in Protocol Buffers?

Tags: multidimensional-array, protocol-buffers

How can I represent a 2-dimensional array in Protocol Buffers?

I need to store `int` and `double` 2d arrays as a field on a PB message, for example:

```
int[][] multi = new int[5][10];
```

I'm using C++, Java and C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language are you using C or C++?

Comment: Did you check this [link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial)?

Comment: @Octopus u linked ur porfile.

Comment: No, the link works for me. May be you clicked on my display name ;)

Comment: @Nocturnal I'm using C++, Java and C# - thanks

Comment: @Keerthivasan Not sure how that link is relevant. That is a most basic introduction to protobufs, and so far as I can tell, makes absolutely no mention of multidimensional arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ProtoBuf-Net, how to (de)serialize a multi-dimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090173/using-protobuf-net-how-to-deserialize-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no direct support in the protocol for this. Your best bet is to have a repeated set of objects that *have* an array each - i.e.

```
message Foo {
    repeated int items = 1;
}
...
repeated Foo foos = 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, when deserisalizing a json payload to the protobuf object.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JustinThomas was the JSON serialized by protobuf? if not: that isn't really a supported scenario in the first place. If you want a general purpose JSON deserializer, *use a general purpose JSON deserializer*, not protobuf's JSON support

Comment: There are extra key "items". It is not a 2-dimensional array without keys.

Comment: How to update matrix data into .proto file in either python or c++.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [structpb](https://google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb). like this:

.proto

```
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
message Foo {
    repeated google.protobuf.Value array = 1;
}
```

.go

```
import (
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
)

...
foo := &Foo{}

items := []interface{}{1,2,3,4,5}
l, err := structpb.NewList(items)
foo.array = append(foo.array, structpb.NewListValue(l))

protojson.Format(foo)  // [[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Comment: Can you show more helpful example?

Answer (score -2):

It does not work.

I look up the grpc guide, which just supports the key-value structure. I advise you:

```
message ListResp { 
   repeated Array list = 1;

}

message Array{
     int64 id = 1; // 
    string name = 2; // 
}
```